# Collect top K elements from multiple sorted arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given multiple sorted arrays,
what's the most efficient way to collect the K largest values from all of them?

**For example:**

**Input:**

```
K = 5

array1: [100, 50, 30, 20, 10]

array2: [400, 50, 20, 0]

array3: [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

**Output:**

```
[400, 100, 50, 50, 30]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all arrays in a priority queue (so in the example, the priority queue would have three values), keyed by the *first* value in those arrays. Use an efficient implementation for the priority queue, like a binary heap.

As you pop an item from the queue, extract the first value from the corresponding array<sup>*</sup>, and if the array is not empty yet, insert it again into the priority queue, now keyed by its *current* first element.

Do this *K* times to get the first *K* values.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>To avoid a non-constant time complexity, instead of really pulling out that value from the array, you can maintain an iterator over the array (like an index that increments...).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Here's an `O(N + (K * log N))` solution, where N is the number of arrays.

First, create a max heap by taking the highest element of each of the N arrays, which can be done in `O(N)` time.

Then, for K iterations:
Pop off the top of the heap in `O(log N)` and insert the element of the corresponding array that follows the one that was just popped off in `O(log N)`.

The loop does `O(log N)` work hence the complexity is `O(N + (K * log N))`

Comment: Correction, creating the max heap only takes `O(N)` time.

Answer (score 0):

These type of problems are solved using priority queue. At every step, we somehow need to find the max element out of max elements of all the arrays. Priority is the key for this. We put the topmost elements of all the arrays along with a reference of the corresponding array in the priority queue. The comparator will just use the value and reference is present so that when we pop an element, we can put the next element of that array in the priority queue.

Attaching the link of a very similar problem so that you can practice along with my solution.
https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-k-sorted-lists/

```
/**
* Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;

 *     ListNode() {}
 *     ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public ListNode mergeKLists(ListNode[] lists) {
        int k = lists.length;
        if(k==0){
            return null;
        }
        PriorityQueue<ListNode> q = new PriorityQueue<ListNode>(k, (x,y)->x.val-y.val);
        for(ListNode list: lists){
            if(list != null)
                q.add(list);
        }
        ListNode ans = new ListNode();
        ListNode temp = ans;
        while(!q.isEmpty()){
            ListNode curr = q.poll();
            temp.next = curr;
            temp = temp.next;
            if(curr.next != null){
                q.add(curr.next);    
            }
        }
        return ans.next;
    }
}
```